# Underline most recent clicked element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng-class, underline

I am trying to find a way to keep track of the most recently clicked item and underline that item only. This is my current approach, however, it is underlining every item I have clicked on but not the most recent one. I also tried to use `:active`, `:focus` and `:focus:active` on `li`, but the underline doesn't stay.

In my HTML:

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'target': isTarget }" (click)="updateTarget(t)"> 
  {{ details }} </li>
```

In my CSS:

```
li { 
  &.target {text-decoration: underline; } 
}
```

In my ts in angular 2:

```
updateTarget(t) {
   this.isTarget = t;
}
```

Comment: what is `t` you are passing in the `updateTarget` function?

Comment: You're going to have to do this in the parent component or a service, as a change to one instance of the child should change its siblings' states.

Comment: `t` is a custom object @Faisal

Comment: OP you wrote that the links you've clicked remain underlined. But I don't understand: Why don't all links get underlined at once when you click on any one of them? Once `isTarget` is set inside `updateTarget()` wouldn't it affect all link styles?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your targets to be an array of json object. Here is how you can do it:

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'target': isTarget === t  }" (click)="isTarget = t">
    {{details }} 
</li>
```

and your styles:

```
.target {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Full code with example in this [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bBYW3tb8RYA37AsllQnO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In your component, have an array, each member of which will correspond to an `<li>` in the view.

```
public target = null; // reference to the most recently clicked link
public links = [
  {details: '...'},
  {details: '...'},    
];
```

Then in your view, use `*ngFor` to iterate through `links`:

```
<li *ngFor="let link of links" [ngClass]="{'target': link===target }" 
    (click)="target = link">
    {{link.details}}
</li>
```

When user clicks a link, Angular will set the underlying object as the current target, and the `ngClass` directive will add the "*target*" class since `link===target` will be true only for the clicked link.