# Underline button text after click within angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Want to exclude DOM manipulation from controller, because it's recommended that Controllers should contain only business logic. I have three buttons, where I want to underline the text of the button if the button was clicked ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rehgy8sv/)):

CSS:

```
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button ng-click="onClick(test.a)">{{test.a.name}}</button>
    <button ng-click="onClick(test.b)">{{test.b.name}}</button>
    <button ng-click="onClick(test.c)">{{test.c.name}}</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = {
        a: {name: "aaa"},
        b: {name: "bbb"},
        c: {name: "ccc"}
    };
    $scope.onClick = function () {
      $("button").removeClass("underline");
      $(event.target).addClass("underline");
     
    };
});
```

I tried to follow this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942223/underline-most-recent-clicked-element) without success:

```
<button ng-class="{ 'underline': select === test.a }" ng-click="onClick(test.a)">{{test.a.name}}</button>

$scope.select = null;
$scope.onClick = function (abc) {
    $scope.select = abc;
};
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtp6yrcu/) for this modification, which throws an syntax error, that I can't resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting ng-class in brackets like this:

```html
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

Comment: thx, `[ngClass]` resolves error msg, but it does not underline the text. Is there an issue with the comparison of the objects `select === test.b` as well?

Comment: Should be @Hölderlin

Comment: had to change the version of the framework within jsfiddle. Now it works as expected.